# Recycler view not showing items in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Fetching data for Recycler view here.but showing no items in recycler view. data is available in database and fetching it in OnCreate() method. 
but when comes to onCreate() method, there is no data. i get data from volley. when i send data to recycler view adapter it is going as empty list
am i missing anything

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Appointment> appList = new ArrayList<>();


String url;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_appointments);
    MyAppointmentAdapter adapter = new MyAppointmentAdapter(getActivity(), appList);
    //here data is not available for appList
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getData();

}




void getData() {
    appList = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    url = "https://newswiftsalon.000webhostapp.com/appointment.php?salonNo=1";

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            System.out.println(response.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
                    appointment.setAppNo(jsonObject.getInt("appNo"));
                    appointment.setFirstName(jsonObject.getString("firstName"));
                    appointment.setStylist(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    appointment.setTime(jsonObject.getString("time"));
                    appointment.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                    appointment.setMobileNo(jsonObject.getString("mobileNo"));
                    appointment.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    appointment.setHsNo(jsonObject.getString("hsNo"));
                    appointment.setStatus(jsonObject.getString("status"));
                    appointment.setSalonNo(jsonObject.getString("salonNo"));

                    appList.add(appointment);
                    //here data available for appList
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already provided the adapter with a data set before your data query is returned.  You'll need to something like the following once your query is finished:

```
((MyAppointmentAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).data = appList;
((MyAppointmentAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: sorry.. where i want to put this code. i dont understand this

Comment: At the bottom of your `onResponse` callback